# SQL Query to Add Leading 0 to part of a column

Tags: sql-server

I need to update a column in SQL to add a leading zero.  Problem is this column has data in it in several formats.

```
0047
0070-0336
0025-0145
0032-0008
0033-0196 Johnson EEOC Matter
```

I need to add a zero before the last 4 digits, or rather just after the dash, but to only the rows that have the 4 digit - 4 digit format (and 4 -4 plus alpha).  So it would look like:

```
0047
0070-00336
0025-00145
0032-00008
0033-00196 Johnson EEOC Matter
```

I have tried several UPDATE and RIGHT statements but cannot get the result I need.

Comment: Simply write some function that implements your logic, and call this function in your UPDATE statment

Comment: This cries out as poor schema design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not tested. Please test it before execution on your real data.

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET col = SUBSTRING(col, 0, CHARINDEX('-', col)) 
    + '-0' + 
    SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('-', col) + 1, LEN(col) - CHARINDEX('-', col))
WHERE col LIKE N'____-____%'
```

This filters only rows with 4 characters, followed by `-`, followed by 4 characters, followed by anything. It sets the column in the following way: put the character from 0 till the first `-` as they are, append `-0` (instead of `-`), then append the rest of column value as they are.

Comment: a litle explain will be nice

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Edited

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Definitely yes. It will not be treated even, because `WHERE` clause will eliminate it

Comment: Yes, the `WHERE` part confuse me, will need to check, but looks like your answer handle every case.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sql `LIKE` uses `_` (underscore) to indicate a single character, and uses `%` to indicate zero or more characters. This will make it clear for you

Comment: I see now. I make it a select to bring all and you update only the ones with 9 digits. I was wondering how you return the rest.

Comment: I fix `CHARINDEX ( expressionToFind ,expressionToSearch [ , start_location ] )`  The parameter were inverted and remove the `-1` because was shorting the second string

Comment: Seems to work great!!  Thank you so much!  I have about 3500 rows to update and several different tables for 1 DB so this was a lifesaver.  Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 3):

what about **[REPLACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms186862(v=sql.120).aspx)**

```
  SELECT REPLACE(YourField, '-', '-0');
  FROM YourTable
```

This will replace the first occurrence of `-`

```
  SELECT STUFF(YourField, CHARINDEX('-', YourField), 1, '-0')
```

But will fail if you have this case

```
 0476       jhonso-jhonson
```

Comment: assumes no other - exists in line (such as Johnson-Johnson.. ) but should cover 95%+  I might be more inclined to case if 5th value in string is a `-` then left 5 + 0 then right remainder of sring

Comment: @xQbert You are right but this is very simple, hope works for OP

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following expression:

```
SELECT IIF(CHARINDEX('-', @COL) <> 0, 
           STUFF(@COL, CHARINDEX('-', @COL), 1, '-0'), 
           @COL)
```

In case of a *4 digit - 4 digit*, or  *4 -4 plus alpha* format, this will replace the ***first*** '-' with a '-0'.

Comment: Do you need the `IFF`?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Yes, to test the case where `@COL = '0045'`.

Comment: Ok, will test... now im worried for this case `0476       jhonso-jhonson`  :(